# Ошибка в регулярном выражении? Django

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, django

Только начинаю осваивать django и сталкиваюсь периодически с разными ошибками. На многие из них ответ нашел здесь, но с этой все никак.Собственно сама ошибка:

> Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['topics/(?P\d+)/$']

views.py

```
def topic(request,topic_id):
    """Выводит однут тему и все ее записи."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic' : topic, 'entries': entries}
    return  render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = (
    # Домашняя страница
    url(r'^$', views.index, name ='index'),

    # Вывод всех тем.
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),

    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
)
```

topics.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<p>Topics</p>
<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'topic' topic_id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li> No topics have benn added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

topic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    {% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

<p> Topic: {{ topic }}</p>
<p> Entries:</p>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p> {{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p> {{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        Нет записей в этом topic.
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'topics' %}">Topics</a>

</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Перехожу по ссылке **http://localhost:8000/topics/** - получаю ошибку. 
Перехожу по ссылке, к примеру http://localhost:8000/topics/1/ - все норм, все отображается...
Python: 3.6
Django: 2.0

Comment: Может, конечно, дело и не в этом, но попробуй заменить `\d` на точное указание допустимых символов `[0-9]`

Comment: Не не, дело точно не в этом) Пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Излазил документацию по Django и все же разобрался...

topics.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<p>Topics</p>
<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
<a href="{{ topic.id }}/"> {{ topic }}</a>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li> No topics have benn added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```